# powershell - get a keyword from query string

Tags: powershell, powershell-4.0

I'm learning PowerShell scripting & want to extract tableName from SQL Query String. For example, I've this query -

```
$q = "SELECT * FROM [TestDB].[dbo].Invoice_Details where Clientname='ABC'"
```

where I want to extract table name i.e. it should output this - ***Invoice_Details***

Currently, I'm doing this with following working code -

```
$q1 = $q -split '\[dbo\]\.'
$q2 = $q1[1] -split ' where '
write-host $q2[0]              #here I get it right (Invoice_Details)
```

But, sometimes the query may/ may not have bracketed names like - `[TestDB].[dbo]`.

So, **I want to optimize this code so that it will work even if query containing any combination of bracketed/ bracketless tableNames**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
$res = ([regex]'(?is)\b(?:from|into|update)\s+(\[?.+\]?\.)?\[?(\[?\w+)\]?').Matches($q)

write-host $res[0].Groups[2].Value
```

Comment: Sorry , I'm did not test, changed index to `2`

Comment: this isn't working for `[tableName]` like - `SELECT * FROM [TestDB].[dbo].[Invoice_Details] where Clientname='ABC'`

Comment: Edited for `[TestDB].[dbo].[Invoice_Details] `